# Choosing between nested and crossed design

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

I'm looking to use a linear mixed effects model. Each participant will rate a given item using 9 scales, 1 of which is the outcome variable. There are 6 items in total. The aim is to determine which predictor is the strongest.

Due to constraints on the duration of testing sessions, we only want each participant to rate 2 of the 6 items. One option is to arbitrarily divide the 6 items into 3 non-overlapping pairs, and then randomly assign one of these pairs to each participant. Does this count as a nested design? If so, does the following R code look right?

```
    mod <-lmer(DV~ 1 + P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5 + P6 + P7 + P8 + (1 + P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5 + P6 + P7 + P8|Participant) + (1 + P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5 + P6 + P7 + P8|item-pairings/item), data =mydata)
```

The other option is to utilize all 15 unique (but overlapping) pairs, and randomly assign one to each participant. Given that the pairs overlap, is this now a crossed design? Should the code look the same as above, but with `item` no longer specified as nested within `item-pairings`? What should I do about `item-pairings` if we go with this design? Enter it as a fixed effect? Theoretically, we're not interested in any effect of item-pairing, but maybe would it be advisable to include it in the model, regardless?

Comment: How many participants are expected? I am thinking that inadvertently we might end up with a crossed design, despite recognising we have a potentially nested design, just because certain items are not replicated enough.

Comment: Based on what is described I would assume that the nesting `participant/item` is relevant too. And also, so many random slopes... are you sure this won't lead to model identifiability issues? At first instance `mod <-lmer(DV~ 1 + P1 + P2 + ... + P8 + (1|Participant/item) + (1 |item_pairings/item), data =mydata)` should be adequate for the second design option.

Comment: Finally the first design case seems to me suboptimal as certain participants won't see a particular item (or item-pairing) by design so how will we distinguish from say item 1 being great (getting high scores all-round) and participant 1 being affluent with her scoring (giving high scores all-round) if item 1 is say in the 1-2 item-pairing and participant 1 is within that pairing. The 15 pair option seems much more robust.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I take your point about the 15-pair option being more robust. I haven't determine the sample size yet, but we can definitely run as many as 1500 participants.

Comment: Cool. That's great then. I was thinking you wanted the first design because of some small sample restrictions. In that sense then, the second design would be an obvious choice for me. And right, now that I think of it I understand why `participant/item` was not picked initially. Yeah, not using probably won't be harmful, if anything it can cause identification issues so dropping it (as you initially did) is probably better.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Just one follow-up question. If each item appears in multiple pairs (as per the 2nd design), that still counts as a nested design? I was thinking that to count as a nested design, each item would have to appear in only 1 pair. Apologies if my basic understanding of the nested/crossed distinction is falling short here!

Comment: No problem at all. I would say yes, if we would think that there might be a framing effect but no, if we think that it won't (be nested). Ultimately the distinction being having "nested" or "crossed" effect would mean distinguishing between using the error structure `(1|item_pairings) + (1|item:item_pairings)` and  `(1|item_pairings) + (1|item)` respectively. Do note that: `(1|item:item_pairings)` is the same as `(1|item)` if  `item` is coded uniquely across `item_pairings`. Conceptually if we assuming no framing effects, then it's not uniquely coded.

Comment: Thanks again. This all makes sense. Getting off topic a little, but would you recommend using simulations to calculate sample size? We have no pilot data, and there aren't really similar studies to go on. Some people in my sub-field seem to just guess the sample size in this situation. I'd like to avoid guessing, if possible, though.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. I would suggest looking at something like [`simr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html) in more detail for that matter. (I will try to write all this in an answer over the weekend.)